# Block merge if github actions are failed

Tags: github, github-actions, github-check-run

I have setup Github action for python app, it's located at
.github/workflows/python-app.yml

with details as

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
...
```

This executes fine however, We want to block if actions fails,
I'm unable to search this status under
`Status checks that are required.`
[image]

Comment: Have you tried giving it a name and then searching by that? Do you see anything at all?

Comment: @rethab have kept default name as `name: Python application` but not able to search with that name

Answer (score 4):

It was issue of `name` inside build which was not there in template

```html
jobs:
  build:
    name: syntax-check

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```